# grinding noise when clutch pedal released

Tags: noise, clutch

I have a 2010 Hyundai Tucson with 5-speed manual transmission. When the engine is cold, there's a loud but brief grinding noise when starting up as the clutch is released. It's been suggested to me that it may be the clutch-release bearing. Is that likely? The clutch (including the release bearing) was replaced just a year ago. When the engine warms up, there's no longer any noise. Starting in second gear isn't different.

Comment: Sounds like the release bearing going bad to me.  Even though it was replaced a year ago, it may have been done improperly.

Comment: It's also been suggested that we may have caused the problem by not lifting off the clutch completely after changing gears, not exactly riding the clutch but perhaps riding the clutch release, if that makes sense.  Is that likely?

Comment: Keeping any pressure on the clutch pedal is a surefire way to accelerate release bearing wear.  Yes, that would be a possible cause.